# SSRS 2008 R2 Color of Tab on Excel Export

Tags: ssrs-2008

Can you set the tab color (like setting the PageName attribute of a tablix group to name the tab) of the Excel export in SSRS 2008 R2? I have poked around but cannot find any options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this can't be done. The ability to name the tab was just added in SSRS 2008 R2.